# Generate dataset from user input

Tags: python, data-structures, user-input

Just started working with Python and I would like to know how to create a set only from user input. 
I'm working on a project where a student has to take some courses, however there are some prerequisites to some of the courses. 
The first line of input from the user will be the number of courses and the total number of dependencies, as such:

```
5 4
```

The next input (however many there may) will be the course IDs and what prerequisites the courses may have, such as:

```
1 3
2 3
4 1
4 2
```

Currently I am just creating it myself, like this:

```
data ={
       '1': set('3'),
       '2': set('3'),
       '4': set('1'),
       '4': set('2')
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of input are you expecting? And does the value in your dictionary have to be a set? If it's a dictionary, the key `4` actually doesn't work as you intend it to: `set('1')` and `set('2')` would overwrite each other if you updated the key. Assuming it's from a file with that specific format and you use sets, you could do something like this:

```
data = {}

with open("file.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        parsed_line = line.split()
        key, value = parsed_line[0], parsed_line[1]

        if key in data:
            data[key].add(value)
        else:
            data[key] = set(value)
```

This would result in something like:
`{'1': {'3'}, '2': {'3'}, '4': {'1', '2'}}`

Comment: I think using sets in this case is prone to issues.  What stops your input number of courses from being the same as the number of thier dependencies?  Why not just a tuple instead?

Comment: I am doing a course, where it is required to be a set. And at the moment, as mentioned before, first input is two values, i.e '5 4' and the next input can be a lot of numbers.